# Django can't upload multiple files and request.FILES seems empty

Tags: python, django, http, upload, request

I'm using django 2.0 and python 3.6, I've tried almost everything to get the values from request.FILES but nothing seems to work, I think that I'm missing something very simple but I can't find it.

**models.py**

```
class Imagen(models.Model):
imagen = models.FileField(max_length=200, blank=True, upload_to='%Y/%m/%d/')
```

**views.py**

```
def prop_add(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    propiedad_instance = Propiedad(tipo = request.POST.get('tipo'), tamano=request.POST.get('tamano'), habitaciones = request.POST.get('habitaciones'), banos = request.POST.get('banos'), descripcion= request.POST.get('descripcion'), direccion= request.POST.GET('descripcion'), precio= request.POST.get('precio'), ubicacion= Ubicacion.objects.get(barrio= request.POST.get('barrio')))  
    propiedad_intance.save()
    for filename in request.FILES.iteritems():
        name = request.FILES[filename].name
        print('name =' + name)  ## <-- not printing anything
        print('file = ' +  file)## <-- not printing anything
        print('filename = ' + filename)## <-- not printing anything
  ubicaciones = Ubicacion.objects.all()
  ctx = {'ubicaciones': ubicaciones}
  return render(request, 'main/add_modal.html', ctx)
```

**HTML template**

```
<form method='post' action=''  enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input name='imagen' type="file" multiple/>
   <button type='submit' class="btn waves-effect">Upload</button>
</form>
```

that views.py is the one that I have right now but so far I've tried all the following variants:

```
**1**
if request.method == 'POST':
  for f in request.FILES.getlist('imagen'):
    filename = f.name
    print(filename) ## <-- not printing anything

**2**
if request.method== 'POST':
  form = FileUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES) ## form imported from forms.py
  if form.is_valid():
     print('form is valid!') ## <-- not printing anything
  else:
     print('form not valid ') ## <-- not printing anything either!! IDK WHY
**3**
if request.method == 'POST':
  print('request.method = "POST" checked ') # <-- Not priting anything! but the model below is being saved to the database! my brain is about to explode right now haha.
  propiedad_instance = Propiedad(tipo = request.POST.get('tipo'), tamano=request.POST.get('tamano'), habitaciones = request.POST.get('habitaciones'), banos = request.POST.get('banos'), descripcion= request.POST.get('descripcion'), direccion= request.POST.GET('descripcion'), precio= request.POST.get('precio'), ubicacion= Ubicacion.objects.get(barrio= request.POST.get('barrio')))    
  propiedad_intance.save()
  files = request.FILES.getlist('imagen')
    if files:
        for f in files:
            print('something') #<-- not printing anything
            print(f) #<-- not printing anything
            print(f.name) <-- not printing anything
    else:
        print('nothing here') #<--- not printing anything
```

**Console log after submitting the form**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNqMt.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please fix your indentation as currently it is not obvious if it is a copy/paste issue or your indentation is the problem itself.

Comment: Sorry about that.

Comment: Added the whole views.py, what add_prop does is showing a form in a modal that lets you add a new house/apartment in a real state website, all the input fields are being saved correctly on the Propiedad model but I noticed that the files weren't being uploaded to my media root and at that moment I changed the code to see what values were in request.FILES at the moment of submitting the form but it seems that request.FILES is empty or something like that since everytime I try to print something in a if or for loop calling request.FILES doesn't do anything ,there's no error on the console..

Comment: Even if a try using a if statement like: if request.FILES: ... else : ... the else statement won't return anything, It's like everytime I call request.FILES django ignores the lines of code that are pointing to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to upload multiple files as per the documentation would be..

```
files = request.FILES.getlist('file_field') #'file_field' --> 'imagen' for you
if form.is_valid():
        for f in files:
            ...  # Do something with each file.
```

Your html looks ok. Replace your view code as per the above and check if its making to the POST in the view?

[Django Docs - Multiple File Upload](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/file-uploads/#uploading-multiple-files)

Comment: Tried that but it didn't work either... I added what I've tried on the last part of my question **3**  , tell me if I made any mistake

Comment: Your no.3 looks ok. Can you add a log/print statement immediately when you are checking for request.POST? Also can you add your entire *view* including the post request to the code?

Comment: Sure! updated view number 3 and uploaded a picture of the console after submitting the form, the print() after the if statement is not running but is saving the model that is in the line below! I think that i'm going crazy right now haha

Comment: Are you using jquery/javscript ? Could be that the submit is being caught and handled using a JQuery .post() so the data isn't actually sent as multipart/form-data.

Comment: That might be the cause! I'm using jquery .load('url to my view') to fill a modal that pops up in the main page so I think that you're right!! Thanks a million for helping me!